# iostream input issue

Tags: c++, dev-c++

When we enter the first value `y` as float, e.g. 2.0, it is printing the answer without allowing an input of the second value `z`. Why?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int add(int x,int y)
{
    int result;
    result=x+y;
    return result;
}

int main()
{

    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    cin>>y>>z;
    x=add(y,z);
    cout<<x;
    getch();
}
```

Comment: cout<<x and include<iostream> and include<conio.h>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extraction from a stream will attempt to consume all the input as long as it is in a format that's valid for the type you're extracting in. For example, with this code

```
int x, y;
cin >> x >> y;
```

and this input:

```
123.456
```

it'll read 123 in `x` and be done. Then, it'll attempt to read an integer in a`y`. Since `123` were already extracted, the first character avaliable is `'.'`. That's not a valid integer and so the `failbit` flag will be set (which you can check by calling `cin.fail()`) on the stream and all further extractions will fail unless you clear the error flags by calling `cin.clear()`.

How to fix this depends on what exactly are you trying to do. You could take doubles instead and check if their decimal part is 0. You could take a whole line of input, put it in a stringstream, extract an integer and check whether there's any garbage left in the stream.

In any case, **check for success of extraction!** Always use stream extraction in some boolean context

```
if (cin >> x) { // <-- implicit conversion of the stream to bool
    // ok, it's safe to use x
} else {
   // an error occured
}
```

of at least check for errros explicitly:

```
cin >> x;
if (cin.fail()) { /* error */ }
```

Comment: But why is it extracting '.' instead of asking to enter new number.Actually 123.456 should  taken as 123 and then other values should be discarded as i hv heard that when we enter float values ,digits after decimal are neglected and before decimal are considered.

Comment: Well, you've heard wrong. A stream will never discard input automatically (it can't read programmers mind, if for no other reason). You need to tell it explicitly, check the function [`ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore).

Answer (score 0):

When you enter a `float value`, say `2.0`, `cin` assigns greedily as many digits in input to y, here `2` and and then looks for a second number (does not take `.` as y is an `integer`). Since it finds `.`, it terminates and discards rest of the input.
Edited your code as it contained syntax errors.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int add(int x,int y)
{
int result;
result=x+y;
return result;
}

int main()
{
int x,y,z;
cin>>y>>z;
x=add(y,z);
cout<<x;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: For that, the variable should be a float, double etc. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Yes, I realized `y` and `z` are ints.

Comment: Note that "assigning 0 to `z`" is only true since C++11. In C++03, `z`'s value would stay untouched (here, it would be left uninitialized).